# Are the Avengers Averse to Mutant Members?

Tags: comics, marvel, avengers

The historical line-ups for the Avengers shows a lot of mutates, humans, or supernatural beings, but very few mutants.

- Captain America (human turned super soldier)
- Hulk (human turned Hulk through Gamma raditation)
- Hawkeye (human at physical peak)
- Ironman (human with advanced suit)
- Ant-Man (human enhanced with Pym particles)
- Wasp (human enhanced with Pym particles)
- Thor (Norse god of thunder)
- Hercules (greek demi-god)

Is there a propensity of the Avengers to be comprised of non-mutants?

Comment: What's the difference between a 'mutate' and a 'mutant'?

Comment: Beast, Namor, Scarlet Witch, Quicksilver, Justice/Marvel Boy, and Firestar, are all mutants; and of course Wolverine and Storm have been Avengers too.

Comment: @DJClayworth a mutate is someone who is human who has powers bestoyed to them through some external force (like a radioactive spider). A mutant is someone born with the genetic X-gene which enables superhuman abilities.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think your sample is a little off...the very first Avengers recruits, after Cap, were Quicksilver and The Scarlet Witch, both mutants (see: Avengers Vol. 1 #16).

However, to discuss this in-continuity, the issue is that the Marvel Universe at large is wary, even scared, of mutants. They do not understand the idea that mutation is a random occurrence and could happen to anyone. They think it makes people monsters, rather than evolved humans. As such, it was tough for the Avengers, at first, to justify adding them to a roster of individuals considered to be the face of super-heroing. In fact, Avengers 16 deals with the idea that Cap has brought on a former criminal (Hawkeye) and two former criminal mutants (Quicksilver/Scarlet Witch) to be the face of the Avengers moving forward.

Namor was the FIRST mutant and was a member for years as well, don't forget. As was Beast, one of the most-loved Avengers from the 70s/80s.

Answer (score 6):

The Avengers are equal-opportunity. You don't even need to have super-powers (e.g. Iron Man, Black Canary) to be an Avenger. Or even be human (e.g. any of the Inhumans or Asgardians). Or even be *alive* (e.g. The Vision).

Now the X-men, ***they*** are the ones with the bias.

Comment: Those X-men... They could learn a thing or two about super-hero discrimination :P

Comment: Now is your chance to answer THAT question: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/14284/has-there-ever-been-a-member-of-the-x-men-who-wasnt-a-mutant

Comment: .. ITYM Black *Widow* ?

Answer (score 2):

No, not at all. This subject is touched on Kurt Busiek's and George Perez's run on the Heroes Return saga. The Avengers are being harassed by the press since they have no Afro-american members, and Iron Man very clearly states the Avengers don't judge members by race or species condition.

The Scarlet Witch has been a member for a long time, and she's a mutant. Also Namor was an Avenger, also a mutant.