# Approximately how many Avengers are born mutants?

Tags: marvel, avengers, mutant

It's clear that many Avengers are NOT mutants (a good starting list was [in this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/14254/are-the-avengers-averse-to-mutant-members)), but some/many are (Namor, Quicksilver, Scarlet Witch, Squirrel Girl).

Is there a good estimate of how many Avengers were mutants (natural born ones, not mutated normal humans like Hulk) compare to the total membership? I'm not looking for exact count, just a reasonably accurate estimate.

You can use any reasonable definition of "Avengers" you wish as long as you clarify who you include in "All Avengers".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No Avengers roster for as long as I have been reading them (nigh on 40 years) has ever had a significant number of mutants on the team. As a matter of fact, the most recent roster is likely to be one of the highest number of mutants simultaneously on the Avengers EVER. At last count there have been an estimated total of 86 to 100 Avengers (if you add on the honorary or posthumously awarded members.) So the percentage of Avengers who have been mutants has been very small in proportion to its membership; it's been an organizational lifetime percentage high of 11%.

- **Scarlet Witch** (first appearance, Avengers #16)
- **Quicksilver** (first appearance, Avengers #16)
- **Beast** (first appearance, Avengers #137)
- **Falcon** (first appearance, Avengers #184)
- **Namor** (first appearance, Avengers #262)
- **Justice** (first appearance, Avengers, vol. 3, #4) (inactive)
- **Firestar** (first appearance, Avengers vol. 3 #4) (inactive)
- **Wolverine** (first appearance, New Avengers vol. 1 #6)
- **Storm** (first appearance, Avengers vol. 4 #19)
- **Squirrel Girl** (first appearance, West Coast Avengers vol. 2, #46)

Active mutant members of the Avengers are: Beast, Wolverine, Storm, Squirrel Girl, Falcon and the Scarlet Witch. You can use the [Avengers list from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Avengers_members) as it is a fairly accurate representative list.

Comment: Do you have Avengers approx count to compare against?

Comment: The following spreadsheet supposedly has every avenger member: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AsaEDlBASy8BdHdUT3ZPR0VyMUR5N3RxT1BSZk1lVGc (Lots of data in Portuguese, sorry about that)

Comment: Something of a late comment, I realise, but is Falcon really a mutant? If he is, he should be part of the X-Men film rights, which belong to Fox.

Comment: Yes, well, depending on when you read it, Falcon's power to communicate with birds was either a latent mutant power or brought about by the use of the Cosmic Cube. If questioned, I am certain Marvel maintains the ambiguity of the power in general. Not to mention the MCU version of the character is just a guy in a specialized flight harness without any powers or bird sidekick. Problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the answer to this question [Who are all these Avengers?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/15751/who-are-all-these-avengers) You will see at least 3 mutants listed. Not included in that picture is Beast.

Storm, Wolverine, Beast, and Squirrel Girl are mutants.

Comment: I would probably slightly prefer non-AvX counts, though this does not invalidate your answer in any way since I didn't mention this preference in the question.