# How big is the intersection between Avengers and X-Men?

Tags: marvel, x-men, avengers

We know that some Marvelverse characters were members of both the X-Men and the Avengers at different times.

Approximately how big is that intersection compared to one-team-only members?

E.g. is it 1%? 10%? 50%?

(I am asking at *any* time, not just during AvX events)

Answer (score 8):

**The overall intersection between the Avengers and the X-men has until the AvX storyline has been almost non-existent.**

- Quicksilver (mutant, early Avenger, recent X-man)
- The Scarlet Witch (mutant, early Avenger, never an X-man)
- The Beast (started an X-man, became an Avenger, one of the longest running mutant members of the Avengers who has also been a charter X-man).

**Other mutant members of the Avengers (who were not X-men):**

- Firestar (reserve Avenger)
- Justice (reserve Avenger)
- Wiccan (Young Avengers)
- Speed (Young Avengers)
- Squirrel Girl (reserve member)

**Recent additions to the Avengers team who are/were also X-men now include:**

- Wolverine (charter New X-man)
- Namor (first mutant, Avenger and now X-man)

**See Also: [How many Avengers were born mutants?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/15969/2765)**

Comment: Assuming that's an exaustive list (I only care about membership in X-men, not being a mutant, BTW); how does that list compare as a fraction of the roster of X-men or Avengers?

Comment: There have been around 80-ish full members of the X-Men. Assuming Thaddeus is correct (and he usually is) then this list represents some 3/80ths or around **3-4%** crossover rate.

Comment: To answer your concern, few X-men have ever been Avengers. I included the mutants to show the Avengers have had mutant members. But X-men rarely become Avengers. Not because they don't want to, but mostly because their first allegiance is to the X-men. Few want to leave the X-men because of their emotional commitment to Xavier's vision. The Avengers are also fairly picky. With the press the X-men get, they try not to get members who may cause negative publicity to the Avengers, who are dependent on goodwill with the government and the public in general.

Answer (score 1):

As of August 7th Storm, Cannonball, Havok and Rogue have also been Avengers. Sunspot is also an Avenger, though never an actual X-Men member; he was in off-shoots of X-Men like the New Mutants, Fallen Angels, and X-Force.